# Convertir Json un objeto en especifico en PHP

Tags: php, json

tengo una consulta espero y puedan darme una respuesta.
Desde el fronted enviare datos de un objeto(pizza), y lo que quiero es poder convertir ese json al objeto(pizza) que tengo en PHP, sin estar asignadolo arguemento por argumento.

```
   //ESTE ES MI JSON
  {
   "numberOfSlice": 4,
   "spoiled": false
   }
```

quiero pasarlo directamente ami objeto(pizza) que tengo en PHP

```
class Pizza extends Consumable{

    private int $numberOfSlice;
    private int $slicesEaten=0;

public function __construct(int $numberOfSlice, bool $spoiled){
    
    $this->numberOfSlice=$numberOfSlice;
    parent::__construct("PIZZA",100,12,false,$spoiled);
}
```

Ya busque informacion, pero lo unico que encontre fue informacion sobre la funcion 'json_encode' y 'json_decode', hasta donde vi no hace lo que yo deseo.
**¿Habra un funcion o forma en PHP de que pueda hacer lo que quiera automticamente?**

Comment: Pregunto, ¿esos datos vienen de una base de datos? De ser así, ¿que API usas para consultar a la BD, `PDO` o `mysqli`? Pregunto porque puedes mapear resultados de la BD a tu clase directamente.

Comment: no es nada relacionado con base de datos, solo es un objeto simple en PHP y tengo que crear ese objeto con valores enviado en formato Json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para algo simple puedes construir tu clase así:

```
class Pizza  extends Consumable {

    private $numberOfSlice;
    private $slicesEaten=0;

    public function __construct($data) {
        foreach ($data as $k => $v) 
        {
            $this->{$k} = $v;
        }
    }
}
```

Y le puedes pasar al constructor el JSON de este modo:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$onePizza = new Pizza($data);
var_dump($onePizza);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(Pizza)#1 (3) {
  ["numberOfSlice":"Pizza":private]=>
  int(4)
  ["slicesEaten":"Pizza":private]=>
  int(0)
  ["spoiled"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Para algo más complejo, verificación de tipos, de nulos, etc, es mejor usar una herramienta de mapeo, por ejemplo [`JSONMapper`](https://github.com/cweiske/jsonmapper) u otra.

Comment: Gracias, JsonMapper es lo mas parecido a lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente no. Un [JSON en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.json.php) normalmente se trata con json_decode para convertirlo a objeto o array.

En tu caso imagino que deberías hacer algo así para recepcionarlo en PHP y pasarle los parámetros a tu nueva instancia de clase **Pizza**:

```php
$obj = json_decode($_POST['json']);  // si el json contiene un objeto y se envia con un POST
$pizza = new Pizza($obj->numberOfSlice, $obj->spoiled);
```